# jQuery file not found when navigating away from home page

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using a function refresh a div with the content from a PHP script which is working fine.

Code below

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
  jQuery('#livenow').load('connect/status.php');
  jQuery('#upnext').load('connect/upnext.php');
}, 5000);
```

But when I navigate away from the home page to another page I'm getting a debugger error of 404 not found as it's trying to search for this script from the current url.

GET http://xxxxxx.co.uk/timetable/connect/status.php 404 (Not Found)

But on the homepage all is well - http://xxxxxx.co.uk/connect/status.php, which is the the absolute file path

The files are in a folder in the root directory - connect/upnext.php

Is there a way I can use the ('connect/status.php'); universally rather than it searching from the current url path?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refer to it by its **absolute** path rather than its **relative** path.  Absolute path starts with a forward slash "/".

Fore example:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
  jQuery('#livenow').load('/connect/status.php');
  jQuery('#upnext').load('/connect/upnext.php');
}, 5000);
```